ESP32 not connecting
I just connected my brand new Hiletgo ESP 32 to my computer, and installed the esp32 library from espressif systems. However, under the "select board and port" section of the Arduino IDE, it is saying that there are "NO DISCOVERABLE PORTS". I have tried refreshing and restarting the computer, but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

I believe this particular board has CP2102 driver IC. You have to install the CP2102 driver software.
